# Shortest way to convert a float to an int

Tags: tips, python

> I'm not really sure if this is the right place to ask this.

Now, I know I can convert a float to an int with `int`, but is there some shorter way?

Comment: Are you looking to floor like `2.7 -> 2`? Or convert already whole-number floats like `4.0 -> 4`? Also, can the number be negative?

Comment: Alan, For one off questions like this that aren't an actual challenge The Nineteenth Byte chat room here is a good place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't actually convert it to an `int` class, but:

Depending on the situation, you may be able to use `x//1`; however, that will actually give a float, so `1.5 // 1` will give `1.0`, not `1`.

Also, this doesn't always work, since `int(-1.5)` is `-1` but `-1.5 // 1` is `-2.0`.

Do with that what you will.

If you use `int(...)` enough times you can assign `i=int`, which breaks even after 3 uses:

```
i=int;i;i;i;i
int;int;int;int
          ^ break-even
```

(For the record, no, you cannot use `x/1` in Python 2, because that's only floor division if both arguments are integers.)

Comment: I use it only one time.

Comment: @AlanBagel then `int` is your best option

Comment: := can also save bytes in specific cases.